# Rich Editor View is not loading text with html

Tags: ios, swift, rich-text-editor

I am using Rich Editor in swift3. When I set HTML editor view value with hard coded string. It shows text with HTML formatting

```
cell.toolbar.editor?.html = "<p>asdfa <strong>mudassir</strong></p>"
```

[image: text with hard coded string]

But when Set editor value with variable that is receiving from server then it just shows simple text while variable has same String

```
                let html = txt
                let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(html!)
                let mytxt = try doc.text()
                cell.toolbar.editor?.html = mytxt
```

[image]

My Code

```
var txt = formValues[objModel.name] as? String
            if txt == nil {
                txt = ""
            }
            do {
                let html = txt
                let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(html!)
                let mytxt = try doc.text()
                cell.htmlEditorView?.html = mytxt
            } catch Exception.Error(let type, let message) {
                print(message)
            } catch {
                print("error")
            }
```

Comment: I still have no problems using a String variable instead of a string literal. You must have some other code that is causing your issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Based on comments, the OP had not been clear about the issue, so this answer is irrelevant.

<s>A quick look at [SwiftSoup](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup) main GitHub page, you'll find:</s>

> **How to remove all the html from a string**
>
> `guard let doc: Document = try? SwiftSoup.parse(html) else { return }`
>
> `guard let txt = try? doc.text() else { return } print(txt)`

So, with the line:

```
let mytxt = try doc.text()
```

you are ***removing*** all html tags from your string.

Pretty sure you want to use:

```
let mytxt = try doc.html()
```

Comment: then label shows  <p>asdfafd<strong>mudassir</strong></p> to

Comment: You need to step through in debug and find out what's going on. What is the value of `txt` in your code? Why are you passing it through `SwiftSoup`? What's the value returned by `doc.html()`? If you are setting the `html` of  `Rich Editor` to that string, and `Rich Editor` is showing the tags, you've got something else going wrong.

Comment: I am receiving this string "&lt;p&gt;asdfa &lt;strong&gt;mudassir&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;" from server. 
then doc.text() returns
<p>asdfa <strong>mudassir</strong></p>"
if i do doc.html() then it returns 
"<html>\n <head></head>\n <body>\n  &lt;p&gt;asdfa &lt;strong&gt;mudassir&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\n </body>\n</html>"
which i should use both don't give text with html formatted

Comment: OK - then yes, you should use `doc.text()`. What happens if you do `let mytxt = "<p>asdfa <strong>mudassir</strong></p>"` and then `cell.toolbar.editor?.html = mytxt`? Does ***that*** gives you properly formatted results?

Comment: if i do with hard coded string then formatted result is shown and if i try second then  it doesn't show formatted result

Comment: If you hard-code `let mytxt = "<p>asdfa <strong>mudassir</strong></p>"` variable, and call `cell.toolbar.editor?.html = mytxt` it works, but `let mytxt = try doc.text()` doesn't? Or do you mean if you hard-code `cell.toolbar.editor?.html = "<p>asdfa <strong>mudassir</strong></p>"` it works?

Comment: cell.toolbar.editor?.html =  "<p>asdfa <strong>mudassir</strong></p>" only this works fine .

Comment: What "Rich Editor" are you using?

Comment: pod 'RichEditorView'

Comment: @Mudassir - ok, assuming you mean this: https://github.com/cjwirth/RichEditorView ... I just grabbed that and ran the "sample" app, made a quick edit to replicate what you're doing, and had no problem setting `toolbar.editor?.html = mytxt`. So, if that is *not* working for you, you're doing something else to cause it to fail. Can't do much more to help you without seeing ***exactly*** what you're doing. See: [mcve]

Comment: i updated question and provide exact code that i am doing